# Chrome Dev Tools adding <br> tags which aren't there?

Tags: html, css, tags

Here is my code, between the image of the audi and the grey block of text chrome is adding 
 tags which are not actually in the code? Anyone know why?  It seems that chrome is adding a lot of tags which are not actually there too :/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Audi MK Advert</title>
            <style>
                @font-face {
                    font-family: 'audibold';
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    src: url('helper-files/fonts/AudiBold.otf') format('opentype');
                }

                @font-face {
                    font-family: 'audinormal';
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    src: url('helper-files/fonts/AudiNormal.otf') format('opentype')
                }

                @media (min-width: 360px) {
                    table .tnormal {
                        font-size: 11px !important;
                    }
                    table .tnormalsmall {
                        font-size: 9px !important;
                    }
                    table .tbold {
                        font-size: 14px !important;
                    }
                    table .tboldaddress {
                        font-size: 13px !important;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    table .tboldsmall {
                        font-size: 11px !important;
                    }
                    table .marshall-logo {
                        margin-left: 100% !important;
                    }
                    table .footer {
                        font-size: 7px !important;
                    }
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>

            <!-- Audi Logo Top Right -->
            <table style="float:right" ; display:block; margin-bottom: 10px>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="helper-files/imgs/logo.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <!-- Grey Navbar -->
            <table style="margin:auto; width:100%; background-color:#858585">
                <tr style="display:block;">
                    <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton2.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
                    <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton3.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
                    <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton4.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
                    <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton5.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
                    <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton6.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
                    <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton1.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
                    <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton7.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- Audi Large Photo -->
            <table style="width:100%; margin-bottom:0">
                <tr>
                    <td style=align: "center"><img src="helper-files/imgs/header.jpg" style="width:100%"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- Body of text -->
            <table style="background-color: lightgray; padding-bottom: 20px; color:grey">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbold" ; style="font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:15px; padding-top: 35px; font-size:35px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;font-family: audibold">Whats in the name?</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tboldsmall" ; style="padding-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; font-family: audibold">To reflect Ridgeway’s acquisition by Marshall Motor Holdings plc in May of this year, effective from the 1st of November, we have rebranded to Marshall.</td>
                </tr>

                <br>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tnormal" ; style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">Don’t worry – it’s not all change. Our excellent staff, standards and values will remain the same, ensuring that you receive consistently high levels of service.</td>
                </tr>

                <br>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tnormal" ; style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">The largest expansion acquisition that Marshall Motor Group has made to date, we are now part of a group that operates 103 franchise dealership businesses representing 24 different manufacturer brands across 25 counties in England, with a
                        turnover in excess of £2.1bn per annum and 3,500 colleagues; but you, the customer, are still our Number One!</td>
                </tr>

                <br>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tnormal" ; style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">With Marshall Motor Group (who are the 7th largest UK motor group in the UK), we are in a better position than ever to exceed expectations and adopt 106 years of dedicated Marshall expertise, with customer care and impeccable industry knowledge
                        at the heart of everything we do.</td>
                </tr>

                <br>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tnormal" ; style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">Just like always, we’re with you for the road ahead. Welcome to the next destination of our exciting journey. As part of the rebrand <a href="http://www.marshall.co.uk/" style="text-decoration:none; color:black; font-weight: bold;">ridgeway.co.uk</a> will
                        redirect to our new online home of <a href="http://www.marshall.co.uk/" style="text-decoration:none; color:black; font-weight: bold">marshall.co.uk</a> for all things Audi sales, service and parts!</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tbold" ; style="font-weight:bold; font-size:35px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audibold">Marshall</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tbold" ; style="font-weight:bold; font-size:35px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audibold">The new name for Audi in Oxford and Newbury.</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: Tables are not layout tools. If your table has only one row or if it has only one column, then you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is invalid. The extra tags you are seeing are a result of the browser attempting to error correct.

You will also see some extra elements "added" where their start and end tags are optional (e.g. every table must have a `tbody`). This is normal behaviour and not a problem.

Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) to identify your errors which includes such things as:

- Line break elements between table rows
- Semi-colons between attributes
- Attribute values with the quotes in the wrong place

Also use a [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) as you also have CSS errors (such as the use of properties which do not exist).